# Rails 3: What is the proper way to respond to REST-ful actions with JSON in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, idioms, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make an API for my rails application using JSON responses to RESTful resource controllers. This is a new experience for me, so I'm looking for some guidance and pointers. To start things off:

1. In a rails application, what is the "proper" way to respond with JSON to REST-ful controller methods? (create, update, destroy)
2. Is there an idiomatic way to indicate success/failure through a JSON response?

---

**Additional information:**

- I'm currently working with rails 3.0.beta2
- I would like to avoid using a plugin or gem to do the grunt work, my goal is to gain a better understanding of how to make a rails 3 API.
- Links to places I could find more information on the topic would also be appreciated, some quick searching on google didn't do me much good.

Comment: Did you figure out this part: "Is there an idiomatic way to indicate success/failure through a JSON response?"

Comment: I haven't been working with rails lately, but from what I've seen in other projects, a boolean flag in the returned JSON object seems to be the most straightforward way to gauge the success/failure of a JSON call.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
#config/routes.rb
MyApplicationsName::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
end

#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ActionController::Base

  # so that respond_with knows which formats are
  # allowed in each of the individual actions
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    respond_with @articles
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @article
  end

  ...

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update_attributes(params[:article])

    # respond_with will automatically check @article.valid?
    # and respond appropriately ... @article.valid? will
    # be set based on whether @article.update_attributes
    # succeeded past all the validations
    # if @article.valid? then respond_with will redirect to
    # to the show page; if !@article.valid? then respond_with
    # will show the :edit view, including @article.errors
    respond_with @article
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I remember seeing `respond_with` in the rails documentation, but for some reason it didn't click. This helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: Does this mean we _need_ to do `<% if @article.valid? %>` logic in the views?

Comment: You need the logic in the views to check whether to show errors. But I updated my answer with more information.

Comment: What about respondind to destroy ? Do you just return json of deleted object or do you jsut send back a header with 200 status ?

Comment: With HTTP `DELETE`, you would return a status of `204 No Content` and an empty body.

Comment: With HTTP `DELETE`, for HTML and browsers, you could also return a redirect to another page, like the index page.