# Rails 3: What's needed to integrate with a REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What do I need to have in my app in order to do GET, PUT, etc requests to a public REST API that answers with JSON?

I'm a little confused with that.

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572571/rails-3-what-is-the-proper-way-to-respond-to-rest-ful-actions-with-json-in-rails

Comment: I dont want to respond, I want to call. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activeresource/README_rdoc.html) was made for that. You can use the [format=](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-format-3D) to make it parse JSON:

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
      self.format = :json
      #...
end
```