# rails - JS callback not executed with remote JSON form (jQuery UJS)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

Consider the following form in .erb view:

```
<%= form_tag(harvester_next_url, :method => "post", :remote => true, "data-type" => :json, :id => "answerForm") do %>
<div id="dynamicFormContent"></div>
<% end %>
```

In certain circumstances, I want to issue a JS callback in the `next` method with
`render :js => "window.location = '#{definitions_path}'"`

However, this does not execute in browser. The response has "window.location..." in body and the `content-type` is set to `text/javascript`, the request's `accept` has `text/javascript`, too.

The Rails version is 3.2.8.

Some additional information: I don't want to switch form action to use JS format as JS callback code is only one of the possible responses from the controller. The other time, I need some JSON from it to deal with.

The question: is there a possibility to make it work **without using client-side redirection** (i.e. getting window.location from JSON response), etc.? AFAIK, this works OK for non-remote forms.

**ADD** It ends up with `status = "parsererror"` when XHR completes. Clearly, this is because jQuery attempts to parse response as JSON, even though it's `text/javascript`. The question is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've got it working. However, I've realized that it is *generally* a dirty approach (you all told me so) to execute incoming JS as-is. But, as long as my question was about that dirty approach, I'll post an idea of how to make it work if you really need it.

Given that we have `parsererror` status in case we supply plain JS, we can:

```
$('#answerForm').on('ajax:error',
  function(e, data, status, xhr)
  {
    $.globalEval(data.responseText);
  }
);
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the callback and do the redirect on the client side:

```
$('#answerForm').on('ajax:success', function(data) {
  if (data.url) {
    window.location = data.url;
  } else {
    // do something else...
  }
})

# -- controller code
render json: {url: definitions_path}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for json, it won't be rendered as javascript immediately, which means you'd need to grab the url from the json response, for instance a `'next-url'` key. You can do that in the ajax callbacks.

Here's some reading that should make what you're trying to do easy:

Rails ujs tutorial (with the callbacks): http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

How to respond to json RESTfully: [Rails 3: What is the proper way to respond to REST-ful actions with JSON in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572571/rails-3-what-is-the-proper-way-to-respond-to-rest-ful-actions-with-json-in-rail)

Also to detect xhr: [Rails detect if request was AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220701/rails-detect-if-request-was-ajax)

Comment: The point is that I'm looking for somewhat unobtrusive way :) Getting URL from JSON response will work as you mentioned, but I want to figure out what's wrong with "render js" approach. Is it completely impossible? Is it a bug or a feature?